# Unable to create new rails project, Strange Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have never had any trouble creating a rails project in the past. I am all of a sudden getting the following error when I run `rails new foobar` from the desktop:

```
bin/rails:6: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting end-of-input
<<<<<<< HEAD
  ^
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how git usually marks conflicts when merging. You should open the `bin/rails` file and manually resolve conflicts.

Edit it, keeping the parts you want. If you're not sure which file gives this error message, search for `<<<<`.

Check also this [guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging), around the middle it presents how a merge conflict looks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a merge conflict in your `bin/rails`. What are the contents.